# json_encode with object oriented PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

How can I code the following json data using the `json_encode` in object oriented PHP.

```
var datasets = {
  "usa": {
    label: "USA",
    data: [[1988, 483994], [1989, 479060], [1990, 457648], [1991, 401949], [1992, 424705], [1993, 402375], [1994, 377867], [1995, 357382], [1996, 337946], [1997, 336185], [1998, 328611], [1999, 329421], [2000, 342172], [2001, 344932], [2002, 387303], [2003, 440813], [2004, 480451], [2005, 504638], [2006, 528692]]
  }

  // skipped other data
}
```

I am quite new in object oriented PHP and with json encodings so I would really appreciate your help.

PS. please post procedural coding style of the script if possible. I just want to compare with OO.

Comment: I hope this is already json encoded. although json_encode() and json_decode() are the functions for the same.

Comment: He wants to json encode an object to get this json output. You didn't understand the question Saurabh.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean. You want to build proper object instances from this data/create data in this format from object instances that contain this data? Or you just want to use `json_encode` somehow in an OOP context? The question as it stands makes little sense/is too vague.

Comment: Note though that this JSON that is presented is pretty weird. The javascript vairable is called "datasets" which imlies you can have more objects than "usa" in there. But you do not have an array that "usa" is inside of. It would make it hard for you to loop over all countries in that JSON data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need Object Oriented to do that :

```
$array = array("usa" => array(
               "label"=>"USA", 
                "data" => array(
                                array("1988","483994"),
                                array("1989","457645") //etc
                          )
                )
          );
 echo json_encode($array);
```

The same works back with the json string like this :

```
$string = '{
  "usa": {
    label: "USA",
    data: [[1988, 483994], [1989, 479060], [1990, 457648], [1991, 401949], [1992, 424705], [1993, 402375], [1994, 377867], [1995, 357382], [1996, 337946], [1997, 336185], [1998, 328611], [1999, 329421], [2000, 342172], [2001, 344932], [2002, 387303], [2003, 440813], [2004, 480451], [2005, 504638], [2006, 528692]]
  }

  // skipped other data
}';

print_r(json_decode($string, true)); //Will show you the previous array
```

See [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: I guess it should be `print_r(json_decode($string, true));` anyway +1

Comment: Thanks, added that to retrieve an assoc array

Comment: oh.. seems like the procedural style isn't bad at all.. thanks~

Answer (score 3):

While others has said that you don't need Object Oriented, obviously you want to do it as object oriented as possible. And I think that's a great idea, object orientation is a heck of a lot better than the procedural crap that most PHP programs consists of.

Try this.

```
<?php

class DataSet {
    var $label;
    var $data;

    public function __construct($label, $data) {
        $this->label = $label;
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}

class CountryData {
    var $datasets;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->datasets = array();
    }

    public function add($label, DataSet $dataset)
    {
        $this->datasets[$label] = $dataset;
    }
}

$usa = new DataSet('USA', array(
    array(1988, 483994),
    array(1989, 479060)
));

$sweden = new DataSet('Sweden', array(
    array(1981, 1000),
    array(1982, 2000)
));

$result = new CountryData();
$result->add('usa', $usa);
$result->add('sweden', $sweden);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Using this approach you can attach logging and other features to the add method etc, the object oriented approach adds the possibility to use industry standard patterns much more easily.

This is what the code above will output

```
{
    "datasets":{
        "usa":{
            "label":"USA",
            "data":[[1988,483994],[1989,479060]]
        },
        "sweden":{
            "label":"Sweden",
            "data":[[1981,1000],[1982,2000]]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer addresses my need of OO implentation for my code. This is what I was looking for, considering OOP. But i decided to go with procedural style in my program and  @soyuka answer works out well.. Thanks for this by the way. :D

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can only be numerical in JSON, so associative arrays are encoded the same as objects. You just need to call `json_encode` as normal:

```
json_encode($array)
```

When decoding JSON in PHP if you want an associative array rather than an object, pass true in as the second parameter:

```
json_decode($json,true);
```

If you want an object you can pass in `false` as the second parameter, or not use it as `false` is the default value for the `associative` parameter in `json_decode`.

Comment: Hi Mitch, hope you're having a tremendous day!