# Object Oriented PHP JSON Encode

Tags: php, json

I've got a simple registration HTML form that takes a name, email and phone number. I've got code that can add this data to a JSON file.

```
    $datafile = ('data/surveycustomers.json');
    $arr = array();

    
    $surveyUser = array (
      'Name' => $name,
      'Email' => $email,
      'Phone' => $phonenum,
    );

    $existingSurveyCustomers = file_get_contents($file);
    $arr_data = json_decode($existingSurveyCustomers, true);
    array_push($arr_data, $surveyUser);
    $existingSurveyCustomers = json_encode($arr_data);
    file_put_contents($file, $existingSurveyCustomers);
```

However, I want to try and do this using OOP but as a newb I've got no idea where I really should be starting so was hoping for some tips to get me going.

Comment: What is under .json file exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json\_encode with object oriented PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291324/json-encode-with-object-oriented-php)

Comment: There's no need for OOP here, all you need is just prepare the proper array and encode it with that simple function. In PHP using associative and non-nonassociative arrays you can build any JSON object you need.

Comment: I suggest you work through one or two "getting started" tutorials for OOP. This is not a topic well suited for the Q&A style here.